# Is there a way to avoid upgrading your qi-gathering array and spirit root in the tutorial?

Tags: immortal-taoists

In *Immortal Taoists*, is there a way to avoid upgrading your qi-gathering array and spirit root in the tutorial? It automatically asks me to upgrade it, I do not want to upgrade it.